# using decorator arguments for switching

Tags: python, decorator

At the flaks library, we can use decorator like switch case. (Did I understand well?)

```
app.route('')
```

So...I would like to make some switch statement with decorators and arguments,

like:

```
@color('pink')
def _pink_power(self):
    print("wow")

@color('blue')
@color('red')
def _powerpower(self):
    print("god!!!!")

def input(color):
    I don't know what to do in here..
    if color is pink, print wow!
```

I was struggling to figure out this quite a long time, but I couldn't make it. Is it impossible do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple way to do it (although I recommend that you change the name of the `input` function at the end because it conflicts with a built-in of the same name):

```
class color:
    _func_map = {}

    def __init__(self, case):
        self.case = case

    def __call__(self, f):
        self._func_map[self.case] = f
        return f

    @classmethod
    def switch(cls, case):
        cls._func_map[case]()


@color('pink')
def _pink_power():
    print("wow")

@color('blue')
@color('red')
def _powerpower():
    print("god!!!!")


def input(colorname):
    color.switch(colorname)

input('pink') # -> wow
input('blue') # -> god!!!!
input('red')  # -> god!!!!
```

---

##### Enhancement

You could support having a default case like C/C++'s `switch` statements support that will be used when there's no matching `colorname`:

```
class color:
    DEFAULT = '_DEFAULT'
    _func_map = {}

    def __init__(self, case):
        self.case = case

    def __call__(self, f):
        self._func_map[self.case] = f
        return f

    @classmethod
    def _default(cls):
        raise ValueError('Unknown color!')

    @classmethod
    def switch(cls, case):
        cls._func_map.get(case, cls._default)()
```

The `_default()` method added to the class raises an exception when it's invoked:

```
input('lavender')  # -> ValueError: Unknown color!
```

However you can override that by defining your own error-handler function:

```
@color(color.DEFAULT)  # Override default function.
def my_default():
    print("loser!")

input('lavender')  # -> loser!
```

Answer (score 1):

You...*could* do this, but I'm not sure it's a great idea to.

```
import contextlib

class Colors(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__colors = dict()

    def register(self, colorname):
        def wrapper(f):
            @contextlib.wraps(f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            self.__colors[colorname] = wrapper
            return wrapper

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__colors[item]

colors = Colors()

@colors.register("pink")
def _pink_power():
    print("wow")

@colors.register("blue")
@colors.register("red")
def _powerpurple():
    print("god!!!!!")

def input(colorname):
    colors[colorname]()
```

Comment: Thank u soooo much but why do you think this is a not good idea?

Comment: I don't think the functionality you gain is worth the weird code structure you have to write. You won't remember why you did this in a year, and definitely won't remember how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it, which I think is an improvement over than my original answer because it's more generic in the sense doesn't require defining a new class for every switch context which makes it more reusable.

The decorator is implemented as a class named lowercase `switch` and the function it's applied to becomes the default function called when a value doesn't match those of any of the associated "case" functions defined.

```
class switch:
    """ Value dispatch function decorator.

    Transforms a function into a value dispatch function, which can have
    different behaviors based on the value of its first argument.
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.registry = {}

    def case(self, value, func=None):
        if func is None:
            return lambda f: self.case(value, f)
        self.registry[value] = func
        return func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.registry.get(args[0], self.func)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Sample usage:

```
@switch
def color(name):  # Default when no match.
    print('loser!')

@color.case('pink')
def _pink_power(name):
    print("wow")

@color.case('blue')
@color.case('red')
def _powerpower(name):
    print("god!!!!")

def input(name):
    color(name)

input('pink')       # -> wow
input('blue')       # -> god!!!!
input('red')        # -> god!!!!
input('lavender')   # -> loser!
```